# How to place the left subfigure more left?

Tags: floats

I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Heron's wind-powered organ}%
[.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[scale=0.58]{Figures/200px-Heron's_Windwheel}}
\subcaptionbox{The Persian, horizontal windmill}
[.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{Figures/persian}}
\end{figure}
```

which generates the following result for the figure:

[image]

I would like the figure(a) to be a little more left.I tried some changes but couldnt find solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: increase your `.4\linewidh` as it is you are only using 80% of the line so 20% is white space

Comment: i tried that but the subfigures are formatted in two rows after this change.or maybe i dont do it correct.dunno.

Comment: as noted in the answer below you have a word space between your subfigures so you need to remove that or keep below .5 as there is not space for two figures each .5\linewidth if there is a space between them,

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you insert the instruction `\hspace*{\fill}` immediately before the second `\subcaptionbox` directive. With this change implemented, the `\centering` instruction after `\begin{figure}[h]` becomes superfluous.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
%%\centering % not necessary
\subcaptionbox{Heron's wind-powered organ}%
      [.4\linewidth]%
      {\includegraphics[scale=0.58]{Figures/200px-Heron's_Windwheel}}
\hspace*{\fill}
\subcaptionbox{The Persian, horizontal windmill}%
      [.4\linewidth]%
      {\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{Figures/persian}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you can handle those spaces manually.
In this case, as for inside a line of text, you can just add horizontal space using the command `\hspace{}`.

You can add negative spaces as well, thus resulting in a backspace.

For example you could do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\hspace{-10mm}
\subcaptionbox{This is caption of picture (a)}%
[.48\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{MyLeftFigure}}
\hspace{10mm}
\subcaptionbox{This is caption of picture (b)}%
[.48\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{MyRightFigure}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The negative space is put before the first picture in order to move it left, the second one moves the second picture right. As a global result, the second picture won't move from its original position.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's better to provide a full example instead of some (extended) fragment of code

Comment: Thank you, @ChristianHupfer. I guess I started with the wrong foot... :)

Comment: @RicoRally: No, mate, good approach, I experienced hspace inside figure and displaymath environments. Welcome ;)

Comment: doesn't work in beamer. It places figures below each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening in your code:

```
|  <----.4---->  <----.4---->  |
                ^--- space
```

- Change the width of the right `\subcaptionbox` to `.6\textwidth`.
- Add `%` after the last argument of the left `\subcaptionbox` to remove the unwanted space.

The result is:

```
|<----.4----><---------.6-------->|
```

The code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Heron's wind-powered organ}%
[.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[scale=0.58]{Figures/200px-Heron's_Windwheel}}
\subcaptionbox{The Persian, horizontal windmill}%
[.6\linewidth]{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{Figures/persian}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.Unfortunatelly it dint work.It placed the figures in diffrent rows.

Comment: doesn't work for me either on beamer.